# CSS transitions on Safari are choppy vs. other browsers

Tags: javascript, css, safari, onclick, transition

I'm really struggling trying to create smooth CSS transitions in Safari. I'm trying to hide/show divs by changing their height with a JavaScript `onclick` event. The resulting transitions are nice and smooth with Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. However with Safari it just looks bad and must be around 15 fps when rendering.

A basic JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/q5a9b62s/6/

The website I'm working on is here: http://www.allinimages.ch/

Thanks.

Comment: Choppiness seems the same to me, browser to browser.  Try moving all of the transformation to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using JavaScript to add a `className` to you `div` like this:

```
    function grow() {
      var element = document.getElementById("boxid");
      if (!element.className) {
        element.className = 'tall';
      } else {
        element.className = '';
      }
    };
```

I've added the nullification of the `className` to enable toggling of the animation.

Then, let CSS processing do all of the transforming for you:

```
    #boxid {
      background-color: red;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease; 
        transition: height 0.3s ease;
    }

    #boxid.tall {
      height: 500px;
      -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease; 
      transition: height 0.3s ease;
      transform: translate3d(100) /* this property ensures GPU processing cross-browser */
    }
```

Codepen example is [here](http://codepen.io/jacefarm/pen/gwJrOZ).

Great article on smooth CSS transitions is [here](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108#.m42lu6v8q).

Some issues for cross-browser use of `translate3d` are documented [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d).